# php soap api call over https not working

Tags: php, apache, web-services, soap, nginx

I have a php soap server api setup on debian with nginx as proxy to apache.
Soap call works fine over http but not over https

nginx configuration is as follows

```
server {

   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name <sub domain name>;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dev/wildcard.<dm name>-chained.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dev/wildcard.<dm name>.key;

   location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

}
  server {
  listen 80;
  # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  server_name <sub domain name>;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://<server ip>:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

and apache configuration is as follows

```
   <VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName <my sub domain>
    ServerAlias www.<my sub domain>


    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/nginx/ssl/dev/wildcard.<dm name>-chained.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/nginx/ssl/dev/wildcard.<dm name>.net.key

    #SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    #SSLVerifyClient none
    #SSLVerifyDepth 1
    #SSLHonorCipherOrder On

   #SSLCipherSuite    

   DocumentRoot /var/www/<project folder>
   <Directory /var/www/<project folder>>
      Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
      SSLRequireSSL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have changed apache ports.conf as follows

```
  NameVirtualHost *:8080
  Listen 8080

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  NameVirtualHost *:8081
  #    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
  #    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
  #    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
  #    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
  #    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
  Listen 8081
 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
   Listen 8081
</IfModule>
```

please advice what did I missed here.
when I use php client in my local and make a soap call it works if the url is http but does not works if the url is https
I don't see any helpful error messages also.

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate for your domain is not going to be valid for localhost so Nginx will reject it. You don't need SSL when connecting to localhost anyway so just make the HTTPS listener of Nginx proxy to the HTTP listener of Apache.

Comment: thanks. I did that change it still does not work.

I changed nginx HTTPS listener conf to 
proxy_pass http://<my server ip>:8080;

I can access soap file using my browser over https without problem
but simple php soap client call does not work

$vLocation = 'https://<url to soap.php>';
  $client = new SoapClient("<url to service.wsdl>",array(
   "location" => $vLocation,
   "trace"=>1,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
   ));
$vFunctions = $client->__getFunctions();

the same php soap application is hosted on a different server where I don't have access to vhost configuration works

Comment: when I do 
openssl s_client -connect <mydomain:443> -ssl3
I get 



` CONNECTED(00000003)
140735331525456:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:`

I have following in my nginx config
ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

any idea